# Is there a way to create a performance counter inside of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, performancecounter

I am working on an app that displays data such as device performance. Inside the app I would like to display some performance information such as branch mispredictions or l2 cache misses that the Counter tool of Xcode's Instruments can display. Is there any way to do this within a native iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I would look how GDPerformanceView is doing for example:
https://github.com/dani-gavrilov/GDPerformanceView-Swift

It shows the used and free memory of the system, I think it could be a good starting point.

Pretty sure you won't be able to access to all the data that Instruments is showing.

Hope it helps